# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web

I'm working with Java web development, using  spring3.1.1+hibernate3.6.0+tomcat7.0.29 + mysql5.5, but after running on my server, Eclipse prompted that

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport
```

and as follows in detail,
type Exception report

```
message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:            org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport

description The server encountered an internal error (Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport



org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)


org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) 
root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) 
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2901)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556) 
cc.fanbang.api.manager.DBManager.addUser(DBManager.java:139) 
 cc.fanbang.api.controller.TestController.handleDBManagerTestRequest(TestController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) 
root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556) 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2901)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678) 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556) 
cc.fanbang.api.manager.DBManager.addUser(DBManager.java:139) 
     cc.fanbang.api.controller.TestController.handleDBManagerTestRequest(TestController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) 
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I can't understand why it told me that no hibernatedaosupport, and I've imported it in the project in referenced libraries and web-inf/lib. 
packages which I've imported as follows,

```
 commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar 
    commons-coder-1.4.jar 
    commons-io-2.3.jar 
    commons-lang-2.6.jar 
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
    ezorph-1.0.6.jar 
    json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar 
    jstl-1.2.jar 
    org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.context-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.core-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.web-3.1.1.release.jar 
    servlet-api.jar 
    antlr-2.7.6 
    c3p0-0.9.1.jar 
    commons-collections-3.1.jar 
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar 
    ehcache-1.5.0.jar 
    hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.final.jar 
    hibernate3.jar 
    javassist-3.12.0.ga.jar 
    jta-1.1.jar 
    mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar 
    org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.release.jar 
    org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.release.jar 
    slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 
    slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar
```

and the part contents of applicationContext.xml related to transaction process as follows,

```
<bean id="transactionManager"           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
</bean> 

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager"> 
    <tx:attributes> 
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" /> 
        <tx:method name="*" /> 
    </tx:attributes> 
</tx:advice> 

<aop:config> 
    <aop:pointcut id="fbPointcut" expression="bean(dbManager)" /> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fbPointcut" /> 
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 3):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class loader cannot find a class which `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport` depends on. Not that `HibernateDaoSupport` itself is missing. The best way to find which dependency is missing is to look at the import section of [`HibernateDaoSupport`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.java.htm)

It seems you are missing `org.springframework.dao` library in your classpath.

Comment: I've changed the version from 3.0.6 to 3.1.1, so the all packages of org.springframework are consistent, but unfortunately, it doesn't work and is the same as previous.

Comment: Besides, I've import org.springframework.dao, which is in org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.release.jar

Comment: you get exact the same exception?

Comment: try changing org.springframework.transaction to org.springframework.tx

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have a different version of `spring-orm` jar in your library which has the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport` class.

Add [spring-orm 3.1 jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-orm%7C3.1.1.RELEASE%7Cjar) to your lib. You can find the jar download link at the bottom.

In general if you get a `NoClassDefFoundError`, google for the jar that has the class. [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) is a good place to do that.

Your spring aop, jdbc and transaction jars are also of different version (3.0.7 and not 3.1.1).  Always use jars of same versions . There are chances that application might throw some error if you use different versions of jars.

Comment: good point but it is not always possible to resolve all spring libraries to use the same version. some version of spring libraries rely on the older spring and sometime cause a problem. For example, i'm using 3.1.2 version for most of my spring libraries but some of these depends on 3.0.7.

Comment: I am not sure about such dependency. I would suggest using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Dependency management becomes a lot more easier. It can get rid of these headaches.

Comment: I've changed the version from 3.0.6 to 3.1.1, so the all packages of org.springframework are consistent, but unfortunately, it doesn't work and is the same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

> 14.3 Hibernate
>
> We will start with a coverage of Hibernate 3 in a Spring environment,
>   using it to demonstrate the approach that Spring takes towards
>   integrating O/R mappers. This section will cover many issues in detail
>   and show different variations of DAO implementations and transaction
>   demarcation. Most of these patterns can be directly translated to all
>   other supported ORM tools. The following sections in this chapter will
>   then cover the other ORM technologies, showing briefer examples there.
>
> Note:   **As of Spring 3.0, Spring requires Hibernate 3.2 or later**.

Source: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate

Your Hibernate Version is too old.

On re-reading your question, you say you are using Hibernate 3.6, yet you list `hibernate3.jar` among your dependencies. Which is it?